# How to loop through a range of cells in Excel using Excel-DNA to build the UDF?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-dna, vba

I'm building a UDF using C# and Excel-DNA. However I hit a brick wall when I was trying loop though the range of cells that is one of the UDF parameters. My first tried was to tranform that range of cells into an array in C#, but I don't know how to do it using Excel-DNA. I'm using the following VBA code to build my C# code.

```
Function my_UDF(stk, F)

Dim i As Integer
z = stk
k = 0
i = 1
sum_if = 0
count_if = 0

Do Until i = 30
    'If F(i) > 0 Then
           If z >= F(i) Then
                z = z - F(i)
                If F(i) > 0 Then
                    k = k + 1
                    sum_if = sum_if + F(i)
                    count_if = count_if + 1
                End If
            Else
                k = k + (z / F(i))
                z = 0
            End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
If z > 0 Then k = k + (z / (sum_if / count_if))
my_UDF = k

End Function
```

In C#, I'm trying to come with something like this:

```
using ExcelDna.Integration;


namespace my_project
{
    public class my_UDF_class
    {
        [ExcelFunction(Name = "my_UDF_function")]
        public static double my_UDF_function(double stk, double f)
        {

            // transform range of cells into array?

            int i = 1;
            double c = 0;
            double sum_f = 0;
            double count_f = 0;

            while (i > 30)
            {
                if (stk >= f(i))
                {
                    stk = stk - f(i);

                    if (f(i) > 0)
                    {
                        c = c + 1;
                        sum_f = sum_f + f(i);
                        count_f = count_f + 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    c = c + (stk / f(i));
                    stk = 0;
                }
                i++;
            }

            if (stk > 0)
            {
                c = c + (stk / (sum_f / count_f));
            }
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Perharps, if there's a way to loop through the cells directly, I don't even need an array.

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of values in your UDF, you'd set the type of the matching parameter to `double[]` for a simple list, `double[,]` for a 2D range or maybe `object[,]` if you're expecting more than numbers.

So your function signature will probably be:

```
public static double my_UDF_function(double stk, double[] f)
```

And you might use the items with code like this:

```
double total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
{
    total = total + f[i];
}
```

- Note that arrays in C# are 0-based.
- You can get the number of items in the array with `f.Length`.
- For 2D arrays you get the number of items in the two dimension with `f.GetLength(0)` and `g.GetLength(1)`.
- You could also do all of this using VB.NET instead of C#.